# Finding the "name" of your Android application

Tags: android

Is there any way to (programatically) find out what your app's name is? I'm specifically talking about the `android:label` property from the application tag in the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="THIS THING HERE!" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <!-- ... -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is android:label set to a resource identifier?  Or is it a static string like in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it... seems a little obtuse though:

```
getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getApplicationInfo())
```

Answer (score 0):

If android:label is set to use a string resource such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <!-- ... -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then you can do:

```
getString(R.string.app_name)
```